# Why in PhpStorm all files were closed?

Tags: phpstorm

I was working in PhpStorm 2020.1.4 and maybe I clicked on some hot key
that all files were closed but IDE not.

Is it some functionality/hot key? I want to disable it...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could happen because of various reasons. First ones that come to mind are:

1. in File | Settings | Keymap:

- *Main Menu | Window | Editor Tabs | Close All Tabs* action
- *Main Menu | Tools | Tasks & Contexts | Clear Context*

2. Branch switching